# Animated Scrolling with SuperScrollorama + Greensocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling, gsap

I'm having a little trouble getting my head around a Javascript animated scroll issue.

I'm using the SuperScrollorama Jquery plugin which is built on-top of the Greensock JS tweening library.

The fundamental effect I'm after is to "pin" a section down, then use vertical scrolling to expand some content, then "unpin" the section once the content is fully expanded, so the user can scroll on - i.e. http://blueribbondesign.com.au/example/

But when I try to apply this same effect to multiple sections one after the other, everything gets all broken: the "unpinned" content below the pinned element is pushed off screen and it  seems to miscalculate the height of the element when it performs the animation in reverse (i.e. scrolling back up the page). - i.e. http://blueribbondesign.com.au/example2/

I've been endlessly fiddling with the "position:fixed" and "pin-spacer" div, and tried attaching the Superscrollorama plugin to various containing elements, but still cannot work  out how to get it to work.

Any help from the brilliant crowd-sourced minds of the web would be much appreciated,

Cheers,

TN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working with this issue myself. What happens is there's a blank div spacer put above the section being pinned with a height that you've defined in the pin() function. Secondly, the pinned element gets a position:fixed assigned to it. Both of these things allow the scroll bar to continue down the page while the element stays affixed. In turn, whatever you had below that section gets bumped down because of that spacer div's height.

If your pinned element is centered horizontally, first give it a left:50%, margin-left:-{width/2}px to fix it from pushing to the left edge.

Next, you'll have to detect the pin/unpin events (which are offered by the plugin as parameters additional to "anim"), and change the section underneath to also toggle a fixed/relative position. When you change that underlying section to be at a fixed position, be sure to set its "top" property to whatever the pinned element's height is. Once the pinned element becomes unpinned, change it back to relative positioning. Does that make any sense?

It seems that different techniques will call for different fixes, but those things are what I'd pay attention to... fixed positioning, and then using the pin/unpin events for adjustment.